# Sorting a YAML output in an ERB template

Tags: ruby, types, yaml, erb, puppet

In an ERB template used by Puppet, I'm trying to sort a YAML output of a hash to make sure it's always the same output.

Here is what I have so far (in `mytest/templates/hash.erb`):

```
<%=
  class MyHash < Hash
    def to_yaml( opts = {} )
      YAML::quick_emit( self, opts ) do |out|
        out.map( taguri, to_yaml_style ) do |map|
          keys.sort.each do |k|
            v = self[k]
            map.add( k, v )
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
  myScope = scope.to_hash.reject{|k,v| k.to_s =~ /(uptime|timestamp|free)/}
  MyHash[myScope].to_yaml
-%>
```

which yields:

```
$ puppet apply -e 'include mytest' --modulepath .
Failed to parse template mytest/hash.erb:
  Filepath: /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb
  Line: 391
  Detail: wrong argument type String (expected Data)
 at /home/rpinson/bas/puppet/mytest/manifests/init.pp:3 on node foo.example.com
```

This is the content of `mytest/manifests/init.pp`:

```
class mytest {
  notify { 'toto':
    message => template('mytest/hash.erb'),
  }
}
```

I can't seem to understand where this type Data comes from, and how to cast the parameters properly in order to get this to work…

Comment: Would you show us at least your `/home/rpinson/bas/puppet/mytest/manifests/init.pp` file? BTW, `quick_emit` seems [to be deprecated](http://apidock.com/ruby/Psych/quick_emit/class) in `Psych`. Do you use `Psych` as `YAML` implementation?

Comment: I add `init.pp` to the question. I have no idea what YAML implementation is used to tell the truth.

Comment: OK, the problem is definitely with `myScope`. Would you `puts myScope` instead of `MyHash[myScope].to_yaml` in the last line of your template and show the output?

Comment: If I do a `p myScope` in the code, it returns a standard hash of key/value pairs corresponding to the facts for the node. Also, returning `myScope.to_yaml` works fine.

Comment: Works fine and _prints what_? And, for the matter of fact, why do you decide to use `quick_emit`? Why not simply wrap to `key.to_yaml`?

Comment: The idea is to redefine `to_yaml` to get a sorted YAML output. If the output is not sorted (which is the default), then the content is different at each run, and the code is not idempotent. I can't put the output of `myScope` or `myScope.to_yaml` here as quite a few data would need to be obfuscated.

Comment: Then call `myScope.to_yaml` and do whatever you want with a result?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the source of problem is [ZAML](https://github.com/hallettj/zaml), YAML replacement which `Puppet` uses for performance purposes.

It can be proved by testing this `erb`-template without `Puppet`.

I'm pretty sure it will work.

I'm investigating to allow to work them together.

UPDATE:

```
ZAML.dump(MyHash[myScope]) # instead of MyHash[myScope].to_yaml
```

This may heal problem, at least it does my one that really similar.